# Issue setting permissions for use of eosio.token in smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, permissions, eosio.token

I have an action in a smart contract called submanager that I want to make use of the transfer action from eosio.token (I'm using eosio.cdt v1.3).

```
ACTION subscribe(name from, name to, asset quantity, std::string memo) {
  require_auth( from );
  eosio::transaction txn{};
  txn.actions.emplace_back(
    eosio::permission_level(from, "active"_n),
    "eosio.token"_n,
    "transfer"_n,
    std::make_tuple(from, to, quantity, memo));
  txn.send(from.value, from);
```

Whenever I push an action using 
`cleos push action submanager subscribe '["bob", "alice", "2.0000 SYS", "memo"]' -p bob@active` I get the following error.

> Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
>   Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.

I assume this error is because I haven't set up permissions correctly, but whenever I try the following `cleos set account permission submanager active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key":"<submanager_pub_key>","weight": 1}], "accounts": [{"permission":{"actor”:”submanager”,”permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' -p submanager@owner` I receive the following error

> Error 3050000: Action validate exception

What am I missing here? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong - I had this command saved in a file in my Notes app along with other cleos commands. The Note app had changed the quotation characters and therefore when I copy/pasted the command was no longer valid.